# Getting the coordinates of an element relative to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was testing out an approach to a solution and found that the methods or functions available for a programmatically triggered JavaScript event is different from ones that are available when the user clicks on the element. For instance, I wasn't able to get the mouse positions of the click event. If the user had clicked, I would have been able to get the mouse positions and a lot more. I am adding the events and triggering it via jQuery. Any reason for this? Any one know how I can get the mouse position after programmatically triggering it using jQuery?

Comment: You can't get the mouse position when triggering the event programatically as the click doesn't have a specific origin.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) jquery function:

```
var clickedPostion = $(this).offset();
alert(e.clientX - clickedPostion.left);
alert(e.clientY - clickedPostion.top);
```

I know the sample it is on click, but you can change it to [mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/)()

Here is a working sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/6wccZ/

Comment: Thanks for the example but your example still requires the user to click it. I wanted one that would be triggered programmatically.

Comment: @k.ken you could try with the update that did on the answer, using mouse move instead, making the div the size you want or just trigger it with the body element, but that I dont know if it will crash the browser..